# Trying to extract "Reply-To" header field in Python, not getting the email address

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I tried to adapt this script I found by searching Google.
Was working perfectly with the previous emails I was receiving, as it was directly extracting the "From" field, and I didn't get the error.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import imaplib
import sys
import email
import re

#FOLDER=sys.argv[1]
FOLDER='folder'
LOGIN='login@gmail.com'
PASSWORD='password'
IMAP_HOST = 'imap.gmail.com'  # Change this according to your provider

email_list = []
email_unique = []

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_HOST)
mail.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
mail.select(FOLDER)

result, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
for i in id_list:
    typ, data = mail.fetch(i,'(RFC822)')
    for response_part in data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
            sender = msg['reply-to'].split()[0]
            address = re.sub(r'[<>]','',sender)
# Ignore any occurences of own email address and add to list
    if not re.search(r'' + re.escape(LOGIN),address) and not address in email_list:
        email_list.append(address)
        print address
```

Comment: email may not have `reply-to`. It is normal.

Comment: all the email does have reply-to. In fact, it's not extracting the email address, that's the only problem here

Comment: if you sure that you email have `reply-to` then use `print()` to see what you have in `msg` and in `msg['reply-to']` and in `msg['reply-to'].split()`

Comment: the result of     msg['reply-to'] is what I'm looking for, but I only need what is contained between < and > (the email address in fact)

Comment: and what do you have in `msg['reply-to'].split()` ? maybe you need `[-1]` instead of `[0]`

Comment: Alright thanks, fixed everything. Simply needed to change that line :
`sender = msg['reply-to'].split()[-1]`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of messing around with string splitting and slicing, the correct approach is to use `parseaddr` from the email.utils package in the standard library. It correctly handles the various legal address formats in email headers.

Some examples:

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> parseaddr("sally@foo.com")
('', 'sally@foo.com')
>>> parseaddr("<sally@foo.com>")
('', 'sally@foo.com')
>>> parseaddr("Sally <sally@foo.com>")
('Sally', 'sally@foo.com')
>>> parseaddr("Sally Smith <sally@foo.com>")
('Sally Smith', 'sally@foo.com')
>>>
```

Also, you shouldn't assume that emails have a Reply-To header. Many do not.